# Already have "pages_messaging" permission, but once the subscription endpoint is called. It says I need to request "pages_messaging"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot, facebook-permissions

To activate bot to page, pages_messaging permission is required as stated in documentation. The permission has been submitted and approved. It's working fine under development mode. But once set to live mode and tried to subscribe chat bot to another page, it throws the following error.

> (#200) To subscribe to the messages field, one of these permissions is needed: pages_messaging. To subscribe to the messaging_postbacks field, one of these permissions is needed: pages_messaging. To subscribe to the messaging_optins field, one of these permissions is needed: pages_messaging. To subscribe to the messaging_referrals field, one of these permissions is needed: pages_messaging. To subscribe to the messaging_policy_enforcement field, one of these permissions is needed: pages_messaging"

Endpoint ===> https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/${page_id}/subscribed_apps?access_token=${access_token}&appsecret_proof=${appsecret_proof}&subscribed_fields=messages,messaging_postbacks,messaging_optins,messaging_referrals,messaging_policy_enforcement

[image: pages_messaging permission already approved]

[image: pages_messaging permission already approved]

[image]

Comment: And, does your access token actually include the permission? Did you send the user through the login flow again, to generate one?

Comment: @CBroe How can I check if token actually include "pages_messaging" permission? Yes, the user is requested to login again. 

Just wondering... if pages_messaging is already approved, shouldn't it be listed under approved item list? It's there when in dev mode. But once set to live mode, it disappears.

Comment: Debug the token.

Comment: @CBore Yeah. you are right. No "pages_messaging" in scopes array. But the permission is already approved for the app instance. Should I remove and resubmit it?

Comment: If it is approved, then try and remove the user’s authorization completely, and have them login again - see if they get asked for that permission then.

Comment: Hi @CBore. It has been a long week! After going back and forth with facebook support team, the issue is finally resolved! Here's what happened.... First of all, you were right about login dialog prompt. "pages_messaging" was not in the list and not requested at all. Having no idea of what's going on, I deleted the permission and resubmitted again assuming that it might be a bug caused during development. I thought maybe I broke something and it doesn't hurt to give a try. Besides, review process "pages_messaging" didn't take longer than a couple of days based on previous experiences.

Comment: It ended up taking a week and the issue still remains. The permission is approved in dev mode, but is not listed when app mode is live and there is no request on facebook login. So, I filed a bug report on facebook support and long story short, it was because i haven't sign "additional contracts"! After signing the contract, the permission finally went live! Here's what I missed...

Comment: I didn't see it [contracts signing status] at first because it turns out only the person who is affiliated with the business manager can see the status of the signing contract.  It shows no hint of signing any contract for someone without access to business manager and yet the business verification is ticked green and says "verified". That's what caused all the confusion. So, for anyone who are experiencing similar issues, please do check if you have the contracts signed even when business verification shows the green mark and also re-submitting an approved permission doesn't solve problem 